# Receiving apps script notifications about 1 per minute

Tags: google-apps-script

I am receiving an apps script notification email about 1 per minute.  I don't think I have any scripts running.  How do I make it stop?

Your script, Unsaved script, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

Details:
Start Function Error Message Trigger End 
6/21/12 1:15 PM myFunction We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. time-based 6/21/12 1:15 PM

Sincerely,

Google Apps Script

Answer (score 2):

You should check if you have some triggers that are running...

to check that  : open or create a spreadsheet go to >tools>script editor > EDIT > all your triggers and see if something is firing every minute.

and... delete it with the `x`

Answer (score 1):

I found I created a script and forgot about it.  Kept getting many notifications.  In my case, it was a script in Google Drive.  Try this:
Open Google Drive
In search bar type: 'app:"Google Apps Script"'
This should list all apps.  find the one with the same name as the notification and edit/disable.

Note, that you may also have a script bound to a google document a.k.a. Addon (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) which can have a trigger built in.

I had to find all spreadsheets and look under Tools (as above) to find the  culprit.  I could not find a way to search for sheets with scripts.

Answer (score -1):

Go to google.com, then click your account picture in the top-right corner of the screen. Next, click Account, then Security, then Review permissions. Click Revoke Access next to the script whose authorization you want to revoke.